# Twitter Api Problem?

Tags: php, html, api, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm using the EpiTwitter getAuthorizeUrl() for Twitter authorization.

the code :

```
<?php
include 'EpiCurl.php';
include 'EpiOAuth.php';
include 'EpiTwitter.php';
require_once 'secret.php';

$Twitter = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
$url = $Twitter->getAuthorizationUrl();
echo '<a href="' .$url. '">Authorize with Twitter</a>';

?>
```

i keep getting this error

"Woah there!

This page is no longer valid. It looks like someone already used the token information you provided. Please return to the site that sent you to this page and try again … it was probably an honest mistake."

The url looks fine, but just doesn't work.

```
http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=
```

im sure the ?oauth_token= must have a value, but its not being generated!! thanks for the help
secrets.php

```
<?php
$consumer_key ='xxx';
$consumer_secret ='xxx';

?>
```

Comment: you can try it out here http://www.kornar.co.uk/tinymce/google/start.php just click `authorise with twitter`

Comment: im thinking its maybe to with CURL, but i checked php_info() its enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out your consumer key and secret once again. Maybe you've typed your variable names wrong. If you used the sample code from [here](http://www.jaisenmathai.com/articles/twitter-php-sign-in.html) straight out of the box, then the variables are `$consumer_key` and `$consumer_secret` - lowercase and underscorized, unlike yours.

Comment: Paste the contents of `secret.php`

Comment: by the way you if your going to answer this question, do it their http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027048/epitwitter-getauthorizeurl-via-ajax-call-not-working i have put 100 points bounty thier ;)

Comment: Look, my answer was right. In your `secret.php` file, **the variable names are different from the ones you're using**. Use this line: `$Twitter = new EpiTwitter('EQjJ2S2eF7IgWjODaX2e2Q', 'VctzdQesHC0FYlZc9izGQhcsiUdbWOM9FJafMI6eBk');` instead of the one you have and it should work. Oh, and you were not supposed to have pasted the actual keys and secret. Now you need to register a new API account. I just wanted to look at your variable names.

Comment: no i have chnaged the variable names wen you told me to, but im still getting the same error, where shall put that piece of code!! :))

Comment: That piece of code needs to replace this: `$Twitter = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);` ... Also, `getAuthorizationUrl()` is deprecated. Use `getAuthorizeUrl()` instead.

Comment: thanks, but it gives me this url now http://www.kornar.co.uk/tinymce/google/Objectid#4 i hate this man!! i really need to work!! is it something to do CURL do u think

Comment: yeh but thats where it links to when i use getAuthorizeUrl(), i think its something wrong with my server, its not generating something for me!

Comment: i think i might have the solution, one of the dependincies is to have php version 5.2 and over for epitwitter library, but my version is php 5.1.6, do you think thats the problem? please i need an answer cheers :))

Comment: it worked, the problem was with the php version, cheers mate you have been brillant!!! :))))))))))

Comment: Glad that you got it sorted :)